# Stack-overflow-style message bar

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, messagebox

I want to create a message bar like the one shown on top of the stack overflow site when you have new notifications. Anyone know how to do this in a good way in Rails/CSS/jQuery, or know of a tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/pJmb7/13/

Note that I can't seem to get the z-index for the close button to supersede the "result" image in jsFiddle so it's pretty hard to find the clickable area of the "x" to demonstrate the closing. But there's just enough sticking out at the bottom for it to work.

If this was not in the jsFiddle sandbox it would appear at the top of the screen.

Comment: Awesome and clean! Thx jamietre

Comment: There's one thing missing though - the Stack Overflow one pushes all other content down when it appears - how would you implement that in the one you pasted?

Comment: That's because the position is set to fixed. If you want the site to flow around it you can either change the `top` of a wrapper for the entire site to move it down, or use `relative` positioning for the div and insert it before any other site content. Updated the example to use relative positioning - I also pushed everything below the "result" image because it was annoying. http://jsfiddle.net/pJmb7/24/ Also shows two ways you can show/hide.

Answer (score 3):

[Basic working event-based example](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/eQ9tw/)

Comment: Just realised that yours actually pushes the other content down ^^

Answer (score -1):

try the jQuery tab, hope that will work :)